# Maximum Possible Difference Between Two Functions of Random Variables?

Tags: real-analysis, probability

- Let $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ be a set of random variables with means $\bar{X_1}, \bar{X_2}, ..., \bar{X_n}$ and sample sizes $n_1, n_2, ..., n_n$.
- We can then define the weighted mean $\bar{X}_{weighted}$ is given by:

$$\overline{X}_{\text{weighted}} = \frac{\sum_{i = 1}^n \overline{x}_i n_i}{\sum_{i = 1}^n n_i}$$

- If you want to calculate the variance of $\bar{X}_{weighted}$, this requires knowing the variances $\text{var}(\bar{x}_1), \text{var}(\bar{x}_2), \dots, \text{var}(\bar{x}_n)$ of each individual $\bar{X_1}, \bar{X_2}, ..., \bar{X_n}$.
- Thus, the variance of the weighted mean can be written as:

$$ \text{var}(\bar{X}_{weighted}) = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}w_i^2\text{var}(\bar{x}_i)}{(\sum_{i=1}^{n}w_i)^2}$$

Where $n$ is the number of groups, $w_i$ is the weight for group $i$, and $\sigma^2_{x_i}$ is the variance of group $i$. Here, $w_i = \frac{n_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}n_i}$.

**My Question:** Suppose we **only** have $\bar{X_1}, \bar{X_2}, ..., \bar{X_n}$ and sample sizes $n_1, n_2, ..., n_n$ **without any knowledge of the variances** .

- From here, we can correctly find out $\bar{X}_{weighted}$ without knowledge of the variances.
- Now, lets say you are interested in calculating $\text{var}(\bar{X}_{weighted})$.
- Lets say that on purpose, we **incorrectly** decide to calculate $\text{var}(\bar{X}_{weighted})$ as

$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\bar{X}_{weighted} - \bar{x}_i)^2}{n-1}$$

Is it possible to determine that without knowledge of variances - **what is the maximum difference possible between the correct formula for the variance of the weighted mean and the incorrect formula for the variance mean?** Is it possible to "bound"  the maximum  possible difference between the correct variance and the incorrect variance? Or is this maximum possible difference infinity?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean $\overline{X}_{\text{weighted}} = \frac{\sum_{i = 1}^n \overline{x}_i n_i}{\sum_{i = 1}^n n_i}$, as in  each $\overline{x}_i $ is a realization of $\overline{X}_i $ right?

Comment: @ 0XLR: Thank you for your reply! Yes, this is what I had in mind - thank you so much!

Comment: The problem is ill posed and confusing, because you mixed the random variables (for example, $X_i$) with their realization (for example, $x_i$). Besides, what is $\bar{X}_1$?  $\bar{X}_1 = \mathbb{E}(X_1)$ or $\bar{X}_1 = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{j=i}^N x_j$ (with $N \in \mathbb{N}$)?

Answer (score 3):

As noted by others, the model is ill-posed.

1. what are $X_i$, $\bar x_i$, $\bar X_i$? From what I understand, $X_i = (X_{i,j})_{j \in J_i}$ is a collection of $|J_i| = n_i$ random variable with empirical mean $\bar X_i = \frac{1}{n_i} \sum_{j\in J_i} X_{i,j}$, and $\bar x_i$ is a realization of $\bar X_i$.
   If that is correct, since the r.v. are not supposed to be distinguished from their **actual** realizations when computing probabilistic quantities, I will not use $\bar x_i$.
2. What hypotheses to you put on the $\bar X_i$? Are they independent? Identically distributed?
   Let me make a wild guess and consider that the $X_{i,j}$ are independent and identically distributed, with (unknown) common variance $\sigma^2$. This implies $\mathrm{var}(\bar X_i) = \sigma^2 / n_i$.
3. You decide to use
   $$ \hat\sigma^2 = \frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^n (\bar X_{\text{weighted}} - \bar X_i)^2 $$
   as an estimator for $\mathrm{var}(\bar X_{\text{weighted}})$. To determine how good it can be, you have to decide **what your metric is**.

> **what is the maximum difference possible between the correct formula for the variance of the weighted mean and the incorrect formula for the variance mean?**

Rephrased: what is the maximum value that $|\hat \sigma^2 - \mathrm{var}(\bar X_{\text{weighted}}) |$ can take with positive probability? This is not a great metric, since if, say, the $X_{i,j}$ are gaussian (and thus, may take arbitrarily large value with positive, albeit tiny, probability), the difference above can be as large as you want.

What you could instead consider is the expected value of the square of that:
$$ \mathbb E\left( |\hat \sigma^2 - \mathrm{var}(\bar X_{\text{weighted}}) |^2 \right) . $$
If this is small, then your estimator $\hat\sigma^2$ is, most of the time, close to the true value.

4. However, in view of its definition, $\hat\sigma^2$ is meant as an estimator of the variance of $\bar X_i$, not of $\bar X_{\text{weighted}}$! Fortunately you can recover an unbiased estimator of $\mathrm{var}(\bar X_{\text{weighted}})$ from $\hat\sigma^2$. See 5- for how to correct that.
5. Now that things are more amenable, let us compute! Without loss of generality we can assume $\mathbb E[X_{i,j}] = 0$.
   The expected value of $\hat \sigma^2$ is then (after some computations)
   $$ \frac 1 n \sum_{j=1}^n \mathrm{var}(\bar X_j) = \sigma^2 \frac 1 n \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{n_j} . $$
   By comparison, in this setting
   $$ \mathrm{var}(\bar X_{\text{weighted}}) = \sigma^2 \frac{\sum_{j=1}^n n_j}{(\sum_{j=1}^n n_j)^2} = \sigma^2 \left(\sum_{j=1}^n n_j\right)^{-1} . $$
   **But $\hat\sigma^2$ is an estimator of $\sigma^2$ and not of $\mathrm{var}(\bar X_{\text{weighted}})$!** Your estimator is thus off by an explicit multiplicative factor; not great, but easy to fix since the $n_j$ are known.
6. How close is the estimator you obtain in this manner? At this point you can do the computations. I expect that if the fourth moment of the r.v. is finite, then, asymptotically, $\mathrm{var}(\hat\sigma^2)$ will be proportional to $\sigma^4$, times a factor that depends on $n$ and the $n_j$.

**To conclude: we need to multiply your estimator by
$$ \frac{n}{\left(\sum_{j=1}^n n_j\right)\left(\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{n_j}\right)} $$
for it to work; once this is done yes, we can indeed bound the error between your estimator and the variance of $\mathrm{var}(X_{\text{weighted}})$.**

Comment: @ Thomas Lehéricy: Thank you so much for your answer! it is very well written and informative!

Comment: Recently I thought of this question here - can you please take a look at it if you have time? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4704477/is-it-possible-to-bound-the-average-sampling-error Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Your estimated variance can be very far from the actual variance. If all $X_i$ are equal then the estimated variance is $0$, but the actual variance is the variance of $X_i$.

If you want to assume independence, then take each $X_i$ to be a constant (not-necessarily all equal). Then the estimated variance can be very high (if the $X_i$ are far, but the true variance is $0$.