# Is it Possible to "Bound" the Average Sampling Error?

Tags: probability

Here is a "game" I recently thought of:

Suppose we have the following information:

- $N_1$ random numbers available from a Probability Distribution Function $f(x)$ : Let's call this set of random numbers as $K_1$
- $N_2$ random numbers sampled from $K_1$ : Let's call this set as $K_2$
- We have knowledge of $E(X)$ and $E(X^2)$
- We have knowledge of the Maximum Likelihood Estimator $\hat{\theta}_{MLE_x}$ : $\hat{\theta}_{MLE_x}$ is an estimator of $E(X)$

**My Question:**

- **Given a set of  $N_1 = n_1, N_2 = n_2, K_1 = k_1, K_2 = k_2, f(x)$ - on average, what is the expected difference between $\hat{\theta}_{MLE_x}$ and $E(X)$ ?**
- **What are the minimum values of $N_1$ and $N_2$ that will produce an average error of $\hat{\theta}_{MLE_x} -  E(x)$ less than some value $\epsilon$**

As an idea, I tried to write a simulation (using R programming language) that corresponds to this game based on a $\mathcal{N}(5,5)$ :

- Step 1: Generate $K_1$ = 100 random numbers from  $\mathcal{N}(5,5)$
- Step 2: Randomly sample $K_2$ = 30 observations from $K_1$
- Step 3: (Using MLE Theory) Calculate the average of $K_2$ (i.e. $\hat{\theta}_{MLE_x}$ ) and subtract from $E(X)$ . Record the value of $\hat{\theta}_{MLE_x}$ - $E(X)$
- Step 4: Repeat Step 2-3 100 times - while recording each individual average $\alpha_1 = \frac{1}{100}\sum_{i=1}^{100}\hat{\theta}_{i_{MLE}}$
- Step 5: Repeat Step 2-4 100 times - record
- Step 6: Repeat Step 1-Step 5 100 times
- Step 7: Make a histogram plot of all $\alpha_i$
- Step 8: Calculate $\bar{\alpha} = \frac{1}{100}\sum_{i=1}^{100}\hat{\theta}_{MLE_x}$

Here is the corresponding R code:

```
set.seed(123)
results <- list()
for (i in 1:100) {
  means <- c()
  for (j in 1:100) {
    data <- rnorm(100, mean = 5, sd = 5)
    samples <- sample(data, 30)
    means[j] <- mean(samples)
  }
  results[[i]] <- means
}

abs_diffs <- sapply(results, function(x) abs(5 - mean(x)))
df <- data.frame(results = abs_diffs)


ggplot(df, aes(x = results)) +
    geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.01, fill = "skyblue", color = "black") +
    labs(title = paste("Distribution of Average Error from True Mean in 100x100 Simulations (Normal~ mu = 5,sigma^2 = 5):",
                       "\nMean =", round(mean(abs_diffs),2), sep = " "),
         x = "Average Error From True Mean", y = "Frequency") +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

Thus, using an empirical simulation based approach - I am able to recover an approximate relationship between $N_1 = n_1, N_2 = n_2, K_1 = k_1, K_2 = k_2, f(x)$  and the average value of $\hat{\theta}_{MLE_x} -  E(x)$.

**But is there more "theoretical relationship" that exists?**

For example, if I choose a Poisson Distribution or a Gamma Distribution (i.e. an arbitrary distribution) with larger variances and smaller sample sizes - how will this affect the average value of $\hat{\theta}_{MLE_x} -  E(x)$? And can this value be bounded?

Thanks!

- **Note**: I am aware that due to the Unbiased property of MLE theory, infinite sized samples will result in 0 error
- However, I am interested in deriving a relationship which can be used to understand : For some distribution $f(x)$, what is "the minimum values of $N_1$ and $N_2$ that will statistically produce an error $\hat{\theta}_{MLE_x} -  E(x)$ less than some value $\epsilon$

Comment: Is this equivalent to your problem?

For fixed $m, k\in \mathbb N$, let $\left(X_{j}\right)_{1\le j\le m}$ be copies of random variable $X$ (which you know $\mathbb E[X]$ and $\mathbb E\left[X^2\right]$) and $N$ subset of $\left\{1,\ldots,m\right\}$ of size $k$ and you want to compute $$\mathbb E\left[\left|\frac1{k}\sum_{j\in N} X_j - \mathbb E\left[X\right]\right|\right]$$

Comment: @ Youem: thank you so much for your reply!

Answer (score 1):

**Preliminary remark:** to talk about the maximum likelihood estimator, you need to consider a model first, i.e. a family $(P_\theta)$ of distribution: the MLE is then the $\theta$ (when unique) that maximizes the observed likelyhood.

What you call the MLE (maximum likelihood estimator) is, I assume from your code, the **[sample mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_mean_and_covariance)** $\bar X_N := \frac 1 N \sum_{j=1}^n X_j$ (sometimes called **empirical mean**), which is a widely used estimator with nice properties.

There are a lot of results on this specific estimator, which you can find in the literature on [concentration inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concentration_inequality#Bounds_on_sums_of_independent_bounded_variables). They give an upper bound on
$ P( |\bar X_n - \mathbb E[X]| > \epsilon ) $ under various conditions. This seems to be what you are looking for.

Comment: @ Thomas: Thank you so much for your answer!

Comment: Just a question - have you ever heard of this theorem before? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4706216/recognizing-a-probability-theorem