# Recognizing a Probability Theorem

Tags: calculus, probability, sequences-and-series, proof-explanation, taylor-expansion

I am reading this article here https://www.jstor.org/stable/3001633 and on page 7, the following probability distribution function is given:

**Theorem**: If $x_1, \dots, x_k$ are independently distributed with density functions: $$f_{n_i}(x_i) = \left(\frac{n_i}{2}\right)^{\frac{n_i}{2}} \frac{x_i^{\frac{n_i}{2}-1}e^{-\frac{n_ix_i}{2}}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n_i}{2}\right)}$$ for $0 \leq x_i < \infty$ and $R(x_1,\dots,x_k)$ is a rational function with no singularities for $0 < x_1,\dots,x_k < \infty$, then $\text{Ave}\{R(x_1,\dots,x_k)\}$ can be expanded in an asymptotic series in $\frac{1}{n_i}$ .
In particular:

$$\text{Ave}\{R(x_1,\dots,x_k)\} = R(1,\dots,1) + \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{1}{n_i} \left.\frac{\partial^2 R}{\partial x_i^2}\right|_{(1,\dots,1)} + O\left(\sum \frac{1}{n_i^2}\right)$$

**My Question:** It looks like in this theorem, the probability distribution $f_{n_i}(x_i)$ is a Chi-Square Distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution) - but does anyone know any more information about this theorem? Does it have a name?

I have been trying to find more information about it to learn where it comes from, why it is useful and why it is true (i.e. proof).

Thanks!

**Note:** Screenshot of the paper in case I transcribed it incorrectly :

[image]

Comment: I've never heard of this theorem, but I may be able to prove it. Would you want that, or are you specifically looking for a citation for the theorem?

Comment: @  forgottenarrow: thank you so much for your reply! I would greatly appreciate anything you would like to do... if you think you can prove it, I would be very interested in learning about this!

Comment: These kinds of problems are really interesting. It seemed relatively simple at first, but I can only get a last term of $O\left(\sum_{i,j,\ell} (n_in_jn_{\ell})^{-1/2}\right)$, so now I'm also interested in seeing a proof. The first two terms are simple. They come from an application of Taylor's theorem and the fact that $E[x_i] = 1$, $\text{Cov}(x_i,x_j) = 0$ and $\text{Var}(x_i) = \frac{2}{n_i}$. To get the last term, you need some way to bound the remainder term from Taylor's theorem.

Comment: The problem is that the bound can depend on $x$. If it was constant, the result would follow from the fact that $E\left[(x_i-1)(x_j-1)(x_{\ell}-1)\right] = \frac{8}{n_i^2}$ if $i=j=\ell$ and $0$ if the three are not equal. However I'm not sure how to control for interactions between the remainder term from Taylor's theorem and $(x_i-1)(x_j-1)(x_{\ell}-1)$ in expectation. That's as far as I was able to get. I hope someone can answer your question.

Comment: Thank you so much for your efforts! it looks like the time is running out for the bounty  :(  ... in an effort to draw more attention, maybe you can upvote this question or put a bounty on it? (it will cost me 100 to put a second bounty on it, but I think only 50 for you)? in any case, i really appreciate your efforts! thanks!